# ASP.Net MVC-How to create dynamically click eventListeners on list items using ViewBag array objects

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add dynamically onClick events on list items. By clicking on them my code needs to change 2 html elements (`<h1>` for the '**selectMovieTitle**' and `<p>` for the '**selectMoviePlot**'), based on the selection. The values will be fetched from the respective ViewBag object.

I have added the javascript code below to the **index.cshtml** file and I fill the `@ViewBag.MoviesListObj` in the respective controller. However, the below code seems that is not executed after reaching the var movies assignment row and moves to **layout.cshtml**  row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        //get all list items in an array
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".movieButtons");
        //create an array in javascript from the ViewBag object. This contains the movies
        var movies =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.MoviesListObj.results));
        //iterate through the list items
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            //for each item add an onClick listener
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
               //by clicking on the respective list item, will change the title and the overview, fetching the value for the movies array, updating a <h1> and <p> element accordingly
               document.getElementById("selectedMovieTitle").innerHTML = movies[i].title;
               document.getElementById("selectedMoviePlot").innerHTML = movies[i].overview;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis after closing click handler function for `buttons`.With that change `movies` is getting value in my test.

Comment: Thank you derloopkat for the observation! indeed I missed the parenthesis. Unfortunately my code still doesn't reach this function. After executing the @Html.Raw row is moving to layout.cshtml at the title tag: <title>Movies Viewer | @ViewBag.Title</title>.

Comment: Make sure these buttons aren't posting back the page. If that's the case you may need to [prevent default](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in your click handler.

Comment: I think this is a possibility.... I have tried putting the e.preventDefault(); in the addEventListener function. However, still doesn't reach that far... Looks like @Html is triggering something that I am not familiar with, skipping the rest of the code

Comment: If you inspect the resulting html code in your browser, it would be clear what's being generated. Also check browser's Console for any error.

Comment: just for the record eventually I completed this by loading the values in a hidden html element and reading the corresponding values via javascript (dirty hack, I know...but it did work)